# Joints in child objects in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I've created a GameObject which contains my rigid body. Then, I created my GameObject which is to be my joint. I had to instantiate these separately for reasons I won't get into here. In other words, I have:

-GameObject A (contains Rigid Body) -GameObject B (contains Joint)

Now, I'd like to attach my joint to its parent object. Usually, I'd give game object A both the Rigid Body and the Joint - but, right now, they're separate. So, my idea was to make B a child of A.

```
 B.transform.parent = A.transform;
```

Then, I would continue as normal.

Well, when I do this, a second rigidbody seems to appear in A. This seems to be created automatically. This is not what I wanted, I wanted B's joint to be attached to A's rigidbody. Without this, the bodies of my kinematic chain are not connected, and it falls apart.

Is there any way to do a "rigid body transplant," and get the behavior I want?

Comment: What do you mean by "GameObject B (contains Joint)"? If you added any sort of joint through `Add component -> Physics -> ___ Joint`, a `rigidbody` will automatically be added to `GameObject B` because any `joints` need `rigidbody`s to work.

Comment: And what is the behavior you want?

Comment: I added these programmatically.  Object B is a child of object A, but I want the joint attached to object A's rigidbody.

Comment: If both Object A and Object B have `rigidbody`s, you can still connect the child's joint to the parent by adding the parent's `rigidbody` to `Connected Body` in the inspector in Unity's editor. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not exactly.  I want the joint to connect two rigidbodies.  The first being the rigidBody in A, and the second being an rigidBody in another object.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that.  connectedBody is the external object.